# External script.js doesn't run in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I have an `https` server. It works except for the external `script.js`. But if the script is internal, it works.

My `server.js` file:

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert'),
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(fs.readFileSync('index.html'));
}).listen(8000, "localhost");
```

My `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style></style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="testFunc();" id="button1"></button>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `script.js` file:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");

alert(); //first alert

function testFunc() {
  alert(); //second alert
}
```

It doesn't work at all, it doesn't even show the first `alert`

I checked the file's name, and it is correct.
Why doesn't it work and what should I do to make it work?

Comment: You are serving the index.html from the server but not the script.js. You should rewrite the express controller so that it handles cases of serving other content (.js, .css, .html), not just the index.html.

Comment: Also, you better rethink the variable naming strategy, as some people might find the current name (butt) inappropriate or offensive.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis oh, sorry, English isn't my first language, so i forgot about meaning of word "butt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point in order to serve the .js file as well:

```js
https.createServer(options,(req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    if ( req.url.endsWith(".js") ){ // If the requested resource ends with .js, then server our script.js file
      return res.end(fs.readFileSync('script.js'))
    }
    // In all other cases, just serve the index.html
    res.end(fs.readFileSync('index.html'));
}).listen(8000, "localhost");
```

Ideally, your controller should be able to serve all sorts of content, with all sorts of filenames (index.html, contact.html, app.js, style.css) based on the extension, .js, .css, .html, etc.

You have to set the appropriate headers as well when serving this content (text/html, text/css, etc.)

[Reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-server-in-node-js-with-the-http-module#step-2-returning-different-types-of-content)

Comment: This is not a correct way of returning a file at all. Now if I go to, for example, `https://localhost:8000/whtever.js` it will return me `script.js` file which is not correct and does not make any sense. Also if I have several `js` files I need to return what do I do then? What about other file types?

Comment: This is exactly what I mention at the end of my answer @Kristiyan.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use `express` from the `npm` package family for creating a server in `NodeJS`. Check out [that link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)

First, you need to install the package:

```bash
npm install express
```

Then just import the package and use it as shown below
File `server.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const indexHTML = fs.readFileSync("index.html");

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("server.cert")
};

const app = express();
const server = https.createServer(options, app);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(indexHTML);
})

server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening at port 8000")
})
```

In the code above I have created a fully working server that returns the `index.html` file when accessing `https://localhost:8000/`. At the same file level as the `server.js` file, you need to create a folder called `public` and in there you need to put all `CSS` and `JS` files you import in the `HTML` files you have.

Now some advice from me for a cleaner code and best practices:

- When listening on the server, it is better to have it in a separate place. That means you need to save the server in a variable and then `.listen()` on that variable
- When using `fs` it is best to read all of the `HTML` files at the top of the file and save the values in a variable that can later be used everywhere. Keep in mind that `NodeJS` is a `single-thread` compiler and what that means is when you read a file with `.readFileSync()` this stops everything else before finishing reading the file. This will make the server slow with more users on it (best practice is to never use `sync` functions on a server).